# Using tasker/sl4a/python to send a text by speaking

Tags: python, speech-to-text, sl4a

I am using `tasker` to send send a text when I speak. However, my `.py` file does not seem to be saving my speech to the clipboard as I though it would. You can see that I am first saving the clipboard as a variable to reset it later in case it is something important.

Here is what I have so far...

1. Variable Set (Name:%SAVECLIP To:%CLIP) If (%CLIP Is Set)
2. Set Clipboard (Text:Not important.)
3. Run Script (Name:SpeechToClip.py)
4. Wait Until (MS: Seconds:2 Minutes:0 Hours:0 Days:0)
5. Send SMS (Number: a number Text:%CLIP)
6. Set Clipboard (Text:%SAVECLIP Add:Off) If (%SAVECLIP Is Set)
7. Variable Clear (Name:%SAVECLIP)

My `.py` file was created in Notepad and then copied into my `sl4a/scripts` folder. Here is what my .py file contains...

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
droid.setClipboard(droid.recognizeSpeech()[1])
```

I think this `.py` file is where the error is occurring because my clipboard is still "Not important." and the text message that is received also says "Not important." instead of what I speak.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution of a day of messing around. This `.py` code seemed to work better...

```
import android    
droid = android.Android()    
text= droid.recognizeSpeech()    
droid.setClipboard(text.result)
```